# Rails Enable and Disable field based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have one checkbox and one text field. Checkbox is of boolean datatype and text field is of integer datatype.

```
 = form.input :user_role, label: t('form.user.user_role')
 = form.input :user_staff, label: t('form.user.user_staff')
```

I want to do two things:

1. When user_role is enabled, make user_staff mandatory
2. When user_role is disabled, disable edit access to user_staff field.

I have added validation for user_staff like:

```
validate :user_staff, presence: true
```

added disabled: true for user_staff field.

But not getting how can we do based on checkbox.

updating my answer:

I have followed this and my problem solved.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33794088/5691295

Now I am working for validation:
when I am clicking on checkbox(i.e checkbox is checked) then only I should use validation.

```
  validate :user_staff, presence: true
```

How can we fix this. Any help appreciates!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem

Add ids to the inputs (rails can do it for you automagically, check it yourself)

```
= form.input :user_role, label: t('form.user.user_role'), id: 'user_role'
= form.input :user_staff, label: t('form.user.user_staff'), id: 'user_staff', required: true
```

Create such script (event may be another: `'turbo:load'` or `'turbolinks:load'`, it depends on your app)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const userRoleCheckbox = document.getElementById('user_role')
  const userStaffField = document.getElementById('user_staff')

  if (!userRoleCheckbox) return
  if (!userStaffField) return

  const updateUserStaffField = () => {
    if (userRoleCheckbox.checked) {
      userStaffField.disabled = false
      userStaffField.required = true
    } else {
      userStaffField.disabled = true
      userStaffField.required = false
    }
  }

  userRoleCheckbox.addEventListener('change', updateUserStaffField)
})
```

If DOM contains checkbox and text field, toggle function is defined and listener for that checkbox

Comment: Instead of using `'DOMContentLoaded'` add an event handler to `document` and catch the event as it bubbles up to the top of the DOM. That way the code works fine with Turbo / UJS and any other AJAX framework as well as avoiding the edge cases where the handler is applied multiple times to the same elements. https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Comment: @mechnicov I have updated my questions with answers and added one more questions. Could you guys help me on that part.